# Makefile include erro

Tags: c++, makefile

I am new to makefile I have this error while compiling.

```
all: main
main.o:ssh-functions.o mysql_connector.o
    g++ -c main.c ssh-functions.o mysql_connector.o -I libuv/include -L libuv/ -luv -lrt -lpthread
ssh-functions.o:ssh-functions.cpp 
    g++ -c  ssh-functions.cpp -lssl -lcrypto 
mysql_connector.o: mysql_connector.c
    g++ -I/usr/include/mysql/ -c mysql_connector.c -L/usr/include/mysql/ -lmysqlclient 

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

output:

```
g++ -c  ssh-functions.cpp -lssl -lcrypto
g++ -I/usr/include/mysql/ -c mysql_connector.c -L/usr/include/mysql/ -lmysqlclient
g++ -c main.c ssh-functions.o mysql_connector.o -I libuv/include -L libuv/ -luv -lrt -lpthread
In file included from main.c:4:0:
mysql_connector.c:4:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: This error is specific for compiler invocation and not so much related to make. The make output will just show you on which target element processing step the error occurred. IMHO you should study a good tutorial about using [tag:make] in combination with a C++ compiler (I'm sure there are plenty of these), or study IDE generated makefiles (e.g. from Eclipse CDT).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `-I/usr/include/mysql` on each compiler invocation that will compile source code that contains `#include <mysql.h>` or equivalent.

You're missing that on the line that compiles `main.c`.

Tip 1: move the `-I` (include search paths) to *before* the source code files you're compiling, and the `-L` (library search paths) and `-l` (libraries) parts to *after* the code files. `-I` is for the preprocessor, that runs *first*. `-L` and `-l` are for the linker, that runs *last*.

Tip 2: do *not* use `-lpthread` unless you know exactly what you're doing. Use `-pthread` instead. And if you need it for one compile, your most likely need it for all the compiles in the same project. (And put that in front of everything, that affects the complete compilation, pre-processor and linker.)

Answer (score 1):

Try s.th. like this (eventually replace `main` with `main.exe` this depends on your target OS environment):

```ml
MY_INCLPATHS=-I /usr/include/mysql -I libuv/include
MY_LIBPATHS=-L /usr/include/mysql -L libuv/
MY_LIBS=-lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -luv -lrt -lpthread

all: main
main: main.o ssh-functions.o mysql_connector.o   
    g++ ${MY_LIBPATHS} main.o ssh-functions.o mysql_connector.o ${MY_LIBS} -o main
main.o: main.c
    g++  ${MY_INCLPATHS} -c main.c
ssh-functions.o: ssh-functions.cpp 
    g++  ${MY_INCLPATHS} -c ssh-functions.cpp
mysql_connector.o: mysql_connector.c
     g++ ${MY_INCLPATHS} -c mysql_connector.c  

clean:
    rm -rf main *.o
```